# Jest in Angular; should I be using the nativeElement or debugElement?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

So as we know, Angular was built with Karma/Jasmine in mind.
But since Jest utilizes jsdom, what would be the performance difference between using debugElement and nativeElement when querying using CSS selectors?